# Как в Sql Explorer создать базу данных sql запросом?

Tags: delphi, sql

Как в Sql Explorer создать базу данных sql запросом?

Comment: телепат отпуск, экстрасенс выходной

Comment: Create Database.. м?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE DATABASE  `base_test` ; 
//простой SQL-запрос
```

Answer (score 0):

таблица какого-либо офиса:

```
CREATE  TABLE    OFFICES  // название таблицы
        (OFFICE   INTEGER (10),//поля данных тип и размер значений которые можно ввести
         CITY  VARCHAR(15),
            REGION   VARCHAR(10),
         TARGET    MONEY,
             SALES    MONEY  
                  PRIMARY KEY(OFFICE));//ключ
```

вводить во вкладку Enter SQL

Comment: Создает **таблицу** , а спрашивают создать **базу**